# UrlReferrer return nothing

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

My webpage has one button and one html `<a>` tag to open the same page. I can get he UrlReferrer by clicking the `<a>` tag. If I clicked the button, the UrlReferrer is nothing. I need to know whether the user clicked  the button to have difference view . Would someone can help me to solve this issue.

There is script on my asp.net page

```
btn.Attributes("onclick") = "window.open('OrderDetails.aspx?btnReserveReleasedClicked=1&orderID=" & objOrder.OrderID & "','_self');return false"


<a href="orderDetails.aspx?OrderID=454057" class="body">Orders</a>
```

Comment: why do you need the urlreferrer when you have a querystring? pretty sure it won't work in this case. I think it works on http redirects. In which case, you could set up a dummy page for button clicks that redirects you to automatically orderdetails.aspx.

Comment: Were you aware that `UrlReferrer` comes from an HTML header which is not guaranteed to be there?

Comment: @JohnSaunders I added the querystring after it doesn't work. Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `UrlReferrer` value because this is the initial request in the chain. In other words, you did not redirect from another ASP.NET resource, thus to ASP.NET you came from nowhere.

Since you are using the query string in your `onclick` attribute, just append a value that tells the `OrderDetails.aspx` page which control called it (button or something else).